# How to get the type of connected monitor(s) on Windows XP?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-xp, monitor, lcd

I need to know the type of the monitor(s) -- i.e. flat screen, CRT, etc -- that is used by the computer from a C++ program. The main requirement is for this code to work on Windows XP SP3 (because otherwise it's almost a given that the system runs on an LCD screen.)

I need it to implement screen dimming to save energy, which will work only on CRTs and have an opposite effect on flat screens.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Very big changes in Vista, supporting new WMI classes to get this kind of info.  Supported by the new LDDM driver model.  XP?  Well, life was *much* simpler 11 year ago.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Unfortunately there're way more XP systems than Vista, where that knowledge is actually needed.... :(

Comment: Interesting. What kind of code are you writing where it could make any difference that it was a CRT, LCD, or LED?

Comment: @AJG85: "Thank you" whoever voted it down. Questions like yours always amaze me. Is it even worth your time asking it if you're not willing to help? I need it to implement screen dimming to save energy, which will work only on CRTs and have an opposite effect on flat screens.

Comment: @ahmd0 I didn't vote either way, was just curious thus the comment.

Comment: This is probably another XY problem. Why do you think that you need this information? Ask about the problem, not about your half-finished solution. There are just too many cornercases, e.g. LCD's not driven at native resolution.

Comment: "I need to know..." - stop. You don't need to know it, not for any sane reason. Go rethink your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most of the Information of Monitor by using the GetMonitorInfo function in Win32 API

```
BOOL GetMonitorInfo(
  __in   HMONITOR hMonitor,
  __out  LPMONITORINFO lpmi
);
```

This will give the output to the structure MONITORINFO or MONITORINFOEX where u can extract the information regarding the Current Attached Monitor

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would I know the type of the monitor from those structures?